# Magick++ - create gif from images

Tags: c++, gif, magick++

I'm trying to create and save a gif with magick++, but every time I try, the result I have is a gif with the first image and no animations. Nothing work.

It seems that `writeImages` only write the first image into the gif.

I've tried:

- https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=33521
- https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15740

Code

```cpp
int width = 300;
int height = 200;
vector<Image> frames;

for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
    Geometry newSize(width, height);
    Image img(newSize, Color("black"));
    img.draw({
        DrawableFont("Helvetica"),
        DrawablePointSize(30),
        DrawableText(width / 2 + i*2, height / 2, to_string(i)),
        DrawableStrokeColor(Color("white")),
        DrawableFillColor(Color("blue"))
    });
    img.animationDelay(500);
    frames.push_back(img);
}

writeImages(frames.begin(), frames.end(), "test.gif");
// Same lines according to this doc: https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/STL.html
Image appended;
appendImages( &appended, frames.begin(), frames.end() );
appended.write("append.gif");
```

Test gif

[image]

Append gif

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but try a bit of detective work. Change the size of your loop (from `20` to `10` say). Does the size of the gif file change? Just trying to work out if you are saving multiple images in the file or not.

Comment: @john Looks like only first image is transferred for unknown reason

Comment: Strange. That's progress but I have no idea what the reason might be.

Comment: The sample I found in the [doc.](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/STL.html) looks a bit different. All images are added to one target image before this is written. Maybe worth a try...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Already tried, the gif result looks a bit different but it's the same result

Comment: Maybe, there is something wrong with your GIF writer. Did you try to produce an animated gif with the command line version of ImageMagick (assuming it's using the same libraries)? It this fails as well you could stop to look for the error in your C++ code, at least.

Comment: I just learnt that ImageMagick seems to provide it's own GIF file I/O: [ImageMagick/gif.c](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/main/coders/gif.c). Maybe, you need an update incl. a check that your Magick++ version matches your ImageMagic version...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat It works thanks, post this as answer to valid it

Answer (score 0):

```
DrawableText(width / 2, height / 2, to_string(i)),
```

... width and height are constant : try to change it for each loop

Comment: It change nothing, but I've updated the post with this new code and image